# Using multithreading while storing records to database

Tags: mysql, multithreading

I am using spring boot, hibernate and mysql, I hit an api which provide records such as Customer data that I want to store in my Customer table of my mysql DB.
I want to optimize this process and so I am thinking of using multithreading, but I am not sure will it be beneficial or not.
I am thinking of using thread pool for hitting api endpoint in order to fetch data and then to put in a Queue data structure.
And another set of threads will access that queue and put data in the database.

My questions are:
1.Is it possible, that is it wont lead to an error?
2. will it be beneficial in terms of performance?

Comment: Mysql supports multiple simultanious connections, so yes, this is possible (you cannot directly influence the number of threads in mysql). Whether multithreading will be beneficial in your particular case, we really cannot know. I thought you have already identified a performance bottleneck concerning inserts into mysql. If you have not, I suggest not to implement multithreading.

Comment: no no error but i will not bebenificuial in order to insert an auto_increment the able has to be blocked

Comment: Thanks shadow and nbk for answering my query.